# How to get Publickey of metamask by Public address?

Tags: web3js, metamask, cryptography, public-key, encryption

I want to get Publickey of metamask by Public address

Comment: It is not possible to recover the public key with only the address, but you could recover it with the address and a signature (for example from a signed transaction).

Answer (score 0):

You can do using a tool like [ethereumjs-utils](https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-util/blob/f53d34aec3213c39d117ddabf25dcbddca13ce83/index.js#L351-L367):

```
/**
 * ECDSA public key recovery from signature
 * @param {Buffer} msgHash
 * @param {Number} v
 * @param {Buffer} r
 * @param {Buffer} s
 * @return {Buffer} publicKey
 */
exports.ecrecover = function (msgHash, v, r, s) {
  const signature = Buffer.concat([exports.setLength(r, 32), exports.setLength(s, 32)], 64)
  const recovery = v - 27
  if (recovery !== 0 && recovery !== 1) {
    throw new Error('Invalid signature v value')
  }
  const senderPubKey = secp256k1.recover(msgHash, signature, recovery)
  return secp256k1.publicKeyConvert(senderPubKey, false).slice(1)
}
```